# Übersetzung von "looked to have earned a valuable point"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> The goal looked to have earned a valuable point for the team.

Wie würde man das übersetzen? Zwei Versuche:

> (a) Das Tor sah aus, einen wertvollen Punkt für die Mannschaft gewonnen zu haben.
>
> (b) Es sah aus, als hätte das Tor einen wertvollen Punkt für die Mannschaft gewonnen.

Sind beide in Ordnung? Falls ja, gibt es einen Unterschied dazwischen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A) ist unvollständig, und b auch nicht besonders schön. Insbesondere weil Tor ja außer dem Treffer auch die drei Latten bezeichnen kann und sich das Gemeinte erst aus dem ganzen Satz erschließt. Mein Vorschlag, der auch das Konkrete, nämlich die Mannschaft in den Mittelpunkt rückt:

> Es sah so aus, als hätte die Mannschaft durch das Tor einen wichtigen Punkt gewonnen.

Answer (score 2):

Wie schon gesagt, a) ist nicht korrekt, b) hingegen schon, aber nicht idiomatisch. Tore gewinnen selbst keine Punkte. Vielmehr gewinnt die Mannschaft durch die Tore Punkte. Wenn Du die Satzstruktur nicht, wie von Em1 und guidot vorgeschlagen, in diesem Sinne umbauen willst, könntest Du sagen, daß das Tor der Mannschaft geholfen hat, einen wertvollen Punkt zu gewinnen. Oder daß es der Mannschaft einen Punkt *beschert* hat:

> Es sah so aus, als hätte das Tor der Mannschaft einen wertvollen Punkt beschert.

Ich würde aber guidots Hinweis ernst nehmen und darauf achten, daß durch den Kontext klar ist, daß "Tor" hier den Treffer bezeichnet und nicht das Gestell. Und da der Satz die Mannschaft in eine eher passive Rolle rückt, käme diese Formulierung für mich vor allem in Betracht, wenn der Treffer eher glücklich, per Zufall zustande gekommen wäre - ein Eigentor des Gegners, ein Abseitstreffer, vielleicht auch ein unberechtigter Elfmeter (falls es überhaupt um Fußball geht).

Answer (score 1):

Version (b) ist grammatikalisch korrekt und entspricht dem englischen

> It looked like the goal had earned a valuable point for the team.

Ich bin allerdings nicht ausreichend bewandert in der Sportreporterfachsprache, um die Gängigkeit dieser Formulierung beurteilen zu können. Gefühlsmäßig würde ich sagen, dass ein Tor nichts gewinnen kann, weil es entweder ein Ding oder ein Ereignis ist.

In Version (a) fehlt jedenfalls etwas. Man könnte sagen

> Das Tor sah aus, als hätte es einen wertvollen Punkt für die Mannschaft gewonnen.

oder ohne die visuelle Komponente

> Das Tor schien einen wertvollen Punkt für die Mannschaft gewonnen zu haben.

(Beide mit derselben Einschränkung wie oben).

Comment: Ich glaube, ich versteh schon den englischen Satz nicht wirklich, aber ich vermute, dass er aussagen soll, dass durch das Tor das Team einen Punkt gewonnen hat (wahrscheinlich der Ausgleichstreffer kurz vor Ende der Spielzeit). Man würde dann im Deutschen einfach sagen: "Die Mannschaft hat durch das Tor einen wichtigen Punkt gewonnen."